# Cakephp text area line break in view

Tags: cakephp

I have added a text area into my form. The problem is when there are line breaks saved, it saves correctly into the database but in the view page, there are no line breaks at all.

Example:
Typed into the text area for the form:
this
is
an
example

Saved into database as:
this
is
an
example

View page shows it as:
this is an example

Anyone got any ideas on how to display the line breaks in the view page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function in your view page.

Comment: also, if it is plaintext, dont forget to use h()! `echo nl2br(h($text));`

Answer (score 3):

HI Please use h() if you are using plain text.

```
echo nl2br(h($your_field_name));
```